# Limit Mongodb field conditionally in Meteor publication

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have this Meteor publication of all the posts in the database.
I would like to return the `owner` field of the post only if the `isAnonymous` field of the post is true (i.e. if the post is anonymous, don't publish the owner?

How do I make this condition in Meteor/Mongodb? The script that I've got here never returns the owner.

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function(id) {
    var posts = Posts.find({},{fields: {owner: 0}},{sort: {created_at: -1}});
    return posts;
});
```

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function(id) {
        var posts = Posts.find({},{fields: {owner: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "isAnonymous", 1 ] }, 0, 1 ] }}},{sort: {created_at: -1}});
        return posts;
    });
```

Comment: You can't use `$cond`  in `.find()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to return a field in some cases only, you can define a transform function for your collection. Something like this:

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts', {
    transform: function(doc) {
        if (-- condition for not returning owner is true --) {
            delete doc.owner;
        }
    }
});
```

If you are ok with returning it, but don't want to display it in some cases, you can do this in the template like so:

```
{{#each posts }}
    ...
    {{#if isOwnerKnown owner }}  
        {{ owner }}
    {{/if }}
    ...
{{/foreach}}

Template.people.helpers({

    isOwnerKnown: function(owner){
        return owner != 'Anonymous';
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: The owner will still be published though, which is very insecure and accessible on the console

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to want here is something like this:

```js
Meteor.publish('posts',function(args) {
    var self = this;

    Posts.find().fetch().forEach(function(post) {
        if ( post.hasOwnProperty("isAnonymous") ) {
            if ( post.isAnonymous ) {
                delete post.owner;
                delete post.isAnonymous;
            }
        }
        self.added("postsFiltered",post._id,post);
    });
    self.ready();
});
```

Then basically define your collection within the client at least as:

```js
Posts = new Meteor.Collection("postsFiltered");
```

And then after you subscribe, the client will only see the data without the "privacy" information as it is always published that way.